# Creating an array to store cell addresses

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am using a VBA script to find the 1's in a 15x15 array. The script finds the row,column address of each cell containing a 1 and maps it to a new (row,column) address based on a mapping table. Below is the excel file:

[image]

And this is the script I'm using to perform this mapping action:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findvalues()
Dim OldRow As Long, OldCol As Long, NewCol As Long, NewRow As Long, OldRowMapped As Long, OldColMapped As Long
Dim oldmappingrow As Variant, oldmappingcol As Variant, c As Range, firstAddress As String, cellAddress As String

With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:o15")
    Set c = .Find(1, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            cellAddress = c.Address
            OldRow = Range(cellAddress).Row
            OldCol = Range(cellAddress).Column

            oldmappingrow = Application.Match(OldRow, Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16"), 0)
            If Not IsError(oldmappingrow) Then
                OldRowMapped = Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16").Cells(oldmappingrow).Offset(, 1).Value
            End If

            oldmappingcol = Application.Match(OldCol, Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16"), 0)
            If Not IsError(oldmappingcol) Then
                OldColMapped = Worksheets(1).Range("r3:r16").Cells(oldmappingcol).Offset(, 1).Value
            End If

            If OldCol > OldRow Then
                NewCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                NewRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
            Else
                NewRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
                NewCol = WorksheetFunction.Min(OldRowMapped, OldColMapped)
            End If

            .Cells(NewRow, NewCol) = .Cells(OldRow, OldCol).Value
            .Cells(OldRow, OldCol).Value = "0"

            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            MsgBox (OldRow & OldCol & " moved to " & NewRow & NewCol)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I need to prevent the `.FindNext()` from mapping values which have already been mapped before.

I thought a good idea would be to store each of the `NewRow, New Col` values in an array and then each loop check that `OldRow, OldCol` does not equal any of the entries in the `NewRow, NewCol` array.

How do I create an array to store the mapped cell addresses and check against them each loop?

Comment: Have a look at Scripting.Dictionary. Far easier than arrays in this case.

Comment: As in store the NewRow, NewCol values as key, item pairs?

Comment: More like (NewRow & "-" & NewCol) as key, and test if it exists.

Comment: Unfortunately as I am on Mac OS that solution won't work since I don't have Microsoft Runtime Script!

Comment: There are replacements available. Here's one: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary I know nothing about it though